# Show percentage time progress bar form submission PHP ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, progress-bar

I have a Bootstrap modal form in page1.php. When I click save, it will pass into page1_process.php and from there it will redirect to page2.php.

page1_process will take some time to process, for that time I want to show a percentage progress bar on modal in page1.php.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't be better and easy to just show a loading gif?

Comment: If the processing runs for long time a progress bar might be nice. On the other hand you could do the processing in the background. Anyway, if you want to show the progress, you will need to know the progress, and you haven't told us anything about that. Can you poll the progress?

Comment: this looks like it might work, using EventSource and Event-Stream: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/show-progress-report-for-long-running-php-scripts.html

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/. As you're using jquery, that might help you.